# Can't override important tag

Tags: css, tags, overriding

on this site I'm working on [www.afrimind.org/test123](http://www.afrimind.org/test123) I'm trying to customise some css for mobile.

There's a popup to subscribe that comes up after 15-30 seconds. If you inspect that, the class .wpp_popup_default_theme .sub_content has a width property (370px) with an important tag. It says the location is at index so I don't know where to change it from, and as it is in a higher position than custom css or style.css so I can't override it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: As your concern is mobile devices why not you using `@media` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#cboxWrapper .wpp_popup_default_theme .sub_content{
 width:400px !important;
}
```

Add this code at the bottom of your CSS.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I completely forgot I could go even higher. Thank you.